# How can I get a list of all available entity view modes?

Tags: 7, entities

I need to have a list of all available view modes for an entity type so I can use it as the `#options` in a select field.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are talking about view modes for entities.

```
$entity_info = entity_get_info('node');
debug(array_keys($entity_info['view modes']));
```

It would result as

```
array (
  0 => 'full',
  1 => 'teaser',
  2 => 'rss',
  3 => 'search_index',
  4 => 'search_result',
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to use this function...

```
field_view_mode_settings($entity_type, $bundle);
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_mode_settings/7